# How to get Twitter bio information with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using Python Tweepy to scrape user information on Twitter.
Currently, I had no problem scraping information such as name, number of followers, and number of followings, but I could not find a way to get bio text data with the current code.
My current code is:

```
test = api.lookup_users(user_ids=['*432899325239793259(arbitrary number)*'])

for user in test:
    print(user, user.name, user.created_at, user.friends_count, user.followers_count)
exit()
```

I have looked at the result of print(user), but there were no information regarding bio information. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The bio is in the field `description` :

```
print(user.screen_name, user.description)
```